# How do I use UIImagePickerController just to display the camera and not take a picture?

Tags: objective-c, iphone, xcode, iphone-sdk-3.0, uiimagepickercontroller

I'd like to know how to open the camera inside of a pre-defined frame (not the entire screen). When the view loads, I have a box, and inside it, I want to display what the camera sees. I don't want to snap a picture, just basically use the camera as a viewfinder. I have searched this site and have not yet found what I'm looking for. Please help.

Thanks!
Thomas

Update 1:

Here is what I have tried so far.

1.) I added UIImageView to my xib.
2.) Connect the following outlet to the UIImageView in IB

IBOutlet UIImageView *cameraWindow;

3.) I put the following code in **viewWillAppear**

```
-(void)viewWillAppear:(BOOL)animated
{
 [super viewWillAppear:animated];
 UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];
 picker.delegate = self;
 
 picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
 [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];

 NSLog(@"viewWillAppear ran");
}
```

But this method does not run, as evident by the absence of NSLog statement from my console. Please help!

Thanks,
Thomas

---

Update 2:

OK I got it to run by putting the code in **viewDidLoad** but my camera still doesn't show up...any suggestions? Anyone....? I've been reading the [UIImagePickerController class reference](http://developer.apple.com/iphone/library/documentation/UIKit/Reference/UIImagePickerController_Class/UIImagePickerController/UIImagePickerController.html), but am kinda unsure how to make sense of it. I'm still learning iPhone, so it's a bit of a struggle. Please help!

```
- (void)viewDidLoad 
{ 
 [super viewDidLoad]; 
 
 // Create a bool variable "camera" and call isSourceTypeAvailable to see if camera exists on device
 BOOL camera = [UIImagePickerController isSourceTypeAvailable:UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera];
 
 // If there is a camera, then display the world throught the viewfinder
 if(camera)
 { 
  UIImagePickerController *picker = [[UIImagePickerController alloc] init];

  // Since I'm not actually taking a picture, is a delegate function necessary?
  picker.delegate = self;
 
  picker.sourceType = UIImagePickerControllerSourceTypeCamera;
  [self presentModalViewController:picker animated:YES];

  NSLog(@"Camera is available");
 }
 
 // Otherwise, do nothing.
 else 
  NSLog(@"No camera available");
}
```

Thanks!
Thomas

---

Update 3:

A-HA! Found this on the Apple Class Reference.

> Discussion
>
> The delegate receives notifications
> when the user picks an image or movie,
> or exits the picker interface. The
> delegate also decides when to dismiss
> the picker interface, so you must
> provide a delegate to use a picker. If
> this property is nil, the picker is
> dismissed immediately if you try to
> show it.

Gonna play around with the delegate now. Then I'm going to read on wtf a delegate is. Backwards? Whatever :-p

---

Update 4:

The two delegate functions for the class are
– imagePickerController:didFinishPickingMediaWithInfo:
– imagePickerControllerDidCancel:

and since I don't actually want to pick an image or give the user the option to cancel, I am just defining the methods. They should never run though....I think.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

add

> [picker
>   dismissModelViewControllerAnimated:YES];

to delegate method bodies.

It will dismiss the view.